# Handle touch events in watch face

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I have a watch face built upon latest API (extending `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine`). Now I'd like to get touch event to have kind of active area in watch face that can be touched to open settings, etc.
A `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine` inherits from `WallpaperService.Engine`, which declares two important methods: `setTouchEventsEnabled(boolean)` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`.

But even when I call `setTouchEventsEnabled(true)` in `onCreate()` method of the `Engine` I never receive a call to `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` in my engine implementation.

Am I doing something wrong or is it simply not possible? I'm aware of some watch faces that offer active areas, but I'm not sure if these are built upon latest API or if they are build upon deprecated API (using layouts and GUI elements).

Answer (score 6):

Use the Interactive Watch Face API in new Android Wear 1.3:

- http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/interacting.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/08/interactive-watch-faces-with-latest.html

UPDATE:

Add just one line to the init function in the `onCreate` function in your `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine` based class:

```
setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(mService)
    .setAcceptsTapEvents(true)
    // other style customizations
    .build());
```

And manage the tap events under

```
@Override
public void onTapCommand(int tapType, int x, int y, long eventTime) { }
```

Notes:

- you'll have to add your own code to find which touch targets (if any) were tapped (`tapType==TAP_TYPE_TAP`)
- you can only detect single, short taps, no swipes or long presses.
- by detecting `TAP_TYPE_TOUCH` and `TAP_TYPE_TOUCH_CANCEL` you can kind of guess swipe gestures, though `TAP_TYPE_TOUCH_CANCEL` doesn't provide the exit coordinates.

For more control your only bet is to add a `SYSTEM_ALERT` layer and toggle it on/off based on information you can gather from `onVisibilityChanged` and `onAmbientModeChanged`...

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: yep, this is correct. refer to official doc pls http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/interacting.html

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible. I guess I read it in a thread on Google Plus on the Android developers group.

The watch face is meant to be a "static" thing, just there, just showing the time. Touch events are never dispatched to it.

The suggested pattern for Settings is to implement it on a companion app on the phone app.

Comment: @Vyacheslav that was a correct answer the time it was posted (2 years ago), now it's an outdated answer.

Comment: I think you have to change it.